# How do I pass a const to my scope

Tags: node.js, express, binance

I m trying to use the node-binance-api to retreive cryptocurency value.

I am able to get the information and display it in the node console.

Im doing so like this;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express(); 
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('mongojs')("mongodb://URL")
var nodeBinanceApi = require("node-binance-api");



const binance = require('node-binance-api')().options({
  APIKEY: '***',
  APISECRET: '***',
  useServerTime: true, // If you get timestamp errors, synchronize to server time at startup
  test: true // If you want to use sandbox mode where orders are simulated
});

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

binance.prices((error, ticker) => {
  console.log("Price: ", ticker);         <--------------------------
  console.log("Price of BTC: ", ticker.BTCUSDT);
  });

 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));

app.listen(81);
```

I would like to pass the json information in ticker to my scope in another script on the page. Should i use routes? and the use get request in the scope?

It does work with routes!

I added

```
app.get('/crypto', function(req, res){
  //calling the function
  binance.prices((error, ticker) => {

    res.jsonp(ticker);
    console.log(ticker);
    });

  return;

  });
```

Now I can see the prices of all cryptosurrency on my page!

Comment: *my scope* - which scope? If you need it inside middleware then place it inside middleware, etc.

Comment: My scope is in the js for the web page where i can see the numbers and do some mat with it. I'm not able to require in the script on the page.

Comment: You won't be able to do that. The script is evaluated on server side and you're trying to access it on client side. This is what web server is for. To send data to client side.

Comment: Yes but if i use a route like /crypto to query the server. The response could be ticker right?

Comment: Yes, this is how it generally should be done. Did you try that? What didn't work? This is primarily Express question then.

Comment: I will add the route part in a few

Comment: Consider adding it as an answer. Self-answers are welcome on SO. This may help somebody else.